# PHP - Evaluate a SOAP response and retrieve a string value from the response

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am trying to retrieve a string value from a soap response but I keep getting an object back no matter what I try. I've tried every solution I've found on StackO. I either get an object back or a null value.

I want the value contained within the "line" element. In this particular response there will only be 1 "line" element returned.

```
$adapterResponse = simplexml_load_string($response);

$Line            = $adapterResponse ->xpath('line');
```

example XML:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns1:executeProcessResponse xmlns:ns1="http://bmc.com/ao/xsd/2008/09/soa">
     <ns1:Output>
        <ns1:Output ns1:type="xs:anyType">
           <ns1:Parameter>
              <ns1:Name>XML_Output</ns1:Name>
              <ns1:Value ns1:type="xs:anyType">
                 <ns1:XmlDoc>
                    <XML_Output>
                       **<line>INVALID</line>**
                    </XML_Output>
                 </ns1:XmlDoc>
              </ns1:Value>
           </ns1:Parameter>
        </ns1:Output>
     </ns1:Output>
  </ns1:executeProcessResponse>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks like the XPath expression is looking for a `<line>` element in the wrong place.  `line` will just look for an element in the current node, if instead you use `//line`, this says look for the node anywhere in the current node...

```
$Line = $adapterResponse ->xpath('//line');
```

So if you then do

```
print_r($Line);
```

you will get

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => INVALID
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert you SOAP response to array and access array elements whatever you required

```
$response = '<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
  <ns1:executeProcessResponse xmlns:ns1="http://bmc.com/ao/xsd/2008/09/soa">
    <ns1:Output>
    <ns1:Output ns1:type="xs:anyType">
       <ns1:Parameter>
          <ns1:Name>XML_Output</ns1:Name>
          <ns1:Value ns1:type="xs:anyType">
             <ns1:XmlDoc>
                <XML_Output>
                   **<line>INVALID</line>**
                </XML_Output>
             </ns1:XmlDoc>
          </ns1:Value>
       </ns1:Parameter>
    </ns1:Output>
 </ns1:Output>
</ns1:executeProcessResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>';

$xmlparser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($xmlparser,$response,$values);
xml_parser_free($xmlparser);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($values);
```

Result like :-

```
 Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [tag] => S:ENVELOPE
        [type] => open
        [level] => 1
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [XMLNS:S] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
            )

        [value] => 

    )
    ....
    ....
    ....
```